# How to set focus on a view when a layout is created and displayed?

Tags: java, android, focus

Currently, I have a layout which contains a `Button`, a `TextView` and an `EditText`. When the layout is displayed, the focus will be automatically put on the `EditText`, which will trigger the keyboard to show up on Android phone. It is not what I want. Is there any way that I can set the focus on `TextView` or on nothing when a layout is displayed?

Answer (score 111):

> Set focus: The framework will handled
>   moving focus in response to user
>   input. To force focus to a specific
>   view, call [requestFocus](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/View.html)()

Answer (score 17):

This works:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: What does it do? It seems like it's modifying some state for the entire activity, and not just a view or fragment, so I'd be cautious about this, and not use it unless I understand all its implications.

Comment: Indeed I would not do this based on the original poster's request.  This may solve the current issue, but using it has side-effects that could cause problems later.

It's hacks like this that make their way into code bases that cause other hacks to be added later on to negate the original hack..the vicious cycle continues....and people wonder why code becomes unmaintainable.  Yep, you guessed it....I work with others who do stuff like this and it makes my life very difficult.

Answer (score 8):

You should add this:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

To set focus, delay the requestFocus() using a Handler.

```
private Handler mHandler= new Handler();

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     LinearLayout mainVw = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     EditText edit = new EditText(this);
     edit.setLayoutParams(params);
     mainVw.addView(edit);

     TextView titleTv = new TextView(this);
     titleTv.setText("test");
     titleTv.setLayoutParams(params);
     mainVw.addView(titleTv);

     mHandler.post(
       new Runnable() 
       {
          public void run() 
          {
            titleTv.requestFocus();
          } 
       }
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Set

```
 android:focusable="true"
```

in your `<EditText/>`

Answer (score 5):

You can try just hidding the keyboard. Something like this:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 4):

Set these lines to `OnResume` as well and make sure if `focusableInTouch` is set to true while you initialize your controls

```
<controlName>.requestFocus();

<controlName>.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: Thanks for `requestFocusFromTouch()`. I added `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` in a container (a problem appeared in API 24).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
comp.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Answer (score 3):

to change the focus make the textView in xml focusable

```
<TextView
            **android:focusable="true"**
            android:id="@+id/tv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in java in on create

`textView.requestFocus();`

or simply hide the keyboard

```
public void hideKeyBoard(Activity act) {
    act.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: android:focusable="true" and textView.requestFocus(); worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The last suggestion is the correct solution. Just to repeat, first set `android:focusable="true"` in the layout `xml` file, then `requestFocus()` on the view in your code.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above works for me. The only (let's say) solution has been to change the first **TextView** in a *disabled* **EditText** that receives focus and then add

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in the *onCreate* callback to prevent keyboard to be shown. Now my first EditText looks like a TextView but can get the initial focus, finally.

Answer (score 1):

i think a text view is not focusable. Try to set the focus on a button for example, or to set the property focusable to true.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an edit text of size "0 dip" as the first control in ur xml, so, that will get the focus on render.(make sure its focusable and all...)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode` to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```xml
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

This will make the keyboard to not show, but `EditText` is still got focus. To solve that, you can set `android:focusableInTouchmode` and `android:focusable` to `true` on your root view.

```xml
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              ...
              >
    <EditText
         ...
       />
    <TextView
         ...
       />
    <Button
         ...
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code above will make sure that `RelativeLayout` is getting focus instead of `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

Focus is for selecting UI components when you are using something besides touch (ie, a d-pad, a keyboard, etc.). Any view can receive focus, though some are not focusable by default. (You can make a view focusable with  `setFocusable(true)` and force it to be focused with `requestFocus()`.)

However, it is important to note that ***when you are in touch mode, focus is disabled***. So if you are using your fingers, changing the focus programmatically doesn't do anything. The exception to this is for views that receive input from an input editor. An `EditText` is such an example. For this special situation `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` is used to let the soft keyboard know where to send input. An `EditText` has this setting by default. The soft keyboard will automatically pop up.

If you don't want the soft keyboard popping up automatically then you can temporarily suppress it as @abeljus noted:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

When a user clicks on the `EditText`, it should still show the keyboard, though.

#### Further reading:

- [Having Trouble Focusing? A Primer on Focus in Android](https://www.novoda.com/blog/do-you-even-focus-bro/)
- [Android Developers Blog: Touch Mode](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html)

Comment: Is this answer wrong? No comment was left with the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
       android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to your Layout to force Talkback/accessibility to go there first.

You really only need the first line, however, the others reinforce to the OS what you want focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Kotlin extension

```
fun View.focusAndShowKeyboard() {
  /**
   * This is to be called when the window already has focus.
   */
  fun View.showTheKeyboardNow() {
    if (isFocused) {
      post {
        // We still post the call, just in case we are being notified of the windows focus
        // but InputMethodManager didn't get properly setup yet.
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
      }
    }
  }

  requestFocus()

  if (hasWindowFocus()) {
    // No need to wait for the window to get focus.
    showTheKeyboardNow()
  } else {
    // We need to wait until the window gets focus.
    viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(
      object : ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener {
        override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
          // This notification will arrive just before the InputMethodManager gets set up.
          if (hasFocus) {
            this@focusAndShowKeyboard.showTheKeyboardNow()
            // It’s very important to remove this listener once we are done.
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(this)
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And just call your `view.focusAndShowKeyboard()` in `override fun onViewCreated(..)` or `override fun OnCreate(..)`

PS: For hiding Views use the following extension

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
  val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Make sure the views are focusable before that using the following android XML attributes, u can also do it programmatically

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```