# Android onFocusChange is fired multiple times

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, listener

I'm using a List Adapter (extends SimpleCursorAdapter) to populate some data.

I'm calling View.SetOnFocusChangeListener in bindView where i attach the listener to the desired EditText. The problem is that the event is fired 4 times where in the end the EditText loses it's focus, until i click again where the event is fired 3 times and the EditText retains focus.

I think it should only be called once.
Is the OnTouch event responsible for this?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {       
    view.setId(cursor.getPosition());//Setting the row id to the corresponding cursor row id for easier data manipulation
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    EditText etItemQuantity = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etItemQuantity);
    if(!isNumeric(etItemQuantity.getText().toString())) {
        etItemQuantity.setFocusable(false);
        etItemQuantity.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        etItemQuantity.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        etItemQuantity.setFocusable(true);
        etItemQuantity.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        etItemQuantity.setClickable(true);
        etItemQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcl);
        etItemQuantity.setOnEditorActionListener(oeal);
    }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    return view;
}

View.OnFocusChangeListener ofcl = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!(v instanceof EditText)) {                     
            return;
        }
        EditText tableEt = (EditText)v;

        if(hasFocus) {
            tableEt.setTag(tableEt.getText().toString());
            tableEt.setText("");
        } else {
            if(tableEt.getText().toString().equals("")) {           
                tableEt.setText(tableEt.getTag().toString());
                tableEt.setTag(null);
            }
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: Create your EditText only once

Comment: there is only one editText created on each row with this Id

Comment: I also have this problem, it is also occured in an adapter. Probably it is because of the fact that Android (in my case Lollipop) runs over all EditText's within ListView or ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line int my activity in the manifest fixed the problem:

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Not sure why though.

Comment: I guess it is because this flag probably prevents the layout from being fired again, which would result in the editor losing focus and regaining focus.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had `onFocusChange` fired twice in API 24.

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    // ... hasFocus
}

container.setOnTouchListener { v, _ ->
    editText.clearFocus()
    hideKeyboard(editText)
    v.performClick()
    return@setOnTouchListener false
}
```

I wanted to remove focus from `EditText` when a user clicks outside of the `EditText`. But in API 24 `editText.clearFocus()` fired `onFocusChange` twice. To set similar behaviour in API 24 and API 30 I added [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63229539/2914140) lines to [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150656/how-to-set-focus-on-a-view-when-a-layout-is-created-and-displayed):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    ....
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <EditText ... />
```

Instead of XML you can change the code so, but in API 30 there may be new problems:

```
editText.clearFocus()
hideKeyboard(editText)
v.performClick()
v.requestFocus() // 1.
v.requestFocusFromTouch() // 2.
return@setOnTouchListener false
```

Comment: I added the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"` to my XML and it worked. But why? Why does allowing the root/parent layout to be focusable resolve this problem?

Comment: @Daniel, good question. I don't know. Probably two links in my answer can help, but I didn't find an answer there.